# Can I read view controller without using objectAtIndex?

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Objective:** When I touch inside a button of "fourthViewController", it checks whether "secondViewController" is placed in the viewController stack without using "objectAtIndex:x". If present, it pops view controllers until the secondViewController is on top.

Present Result:

```
2014-03-11 10:44:54.187 Test_Push[320:11303] (
"<HomeViewController: 0x7153bd0>",
"<secondViewController: 0x71636c0>",
"<thirdViewController: 0x71648e0>",
"<fourthViewController: 0x7128b60>"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
for (UIViewController *viewcontroller in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {
    if ([viewcontroller isKindOfClass: [secondViewController class]]){

        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Its Works!!! But a convention mistake. Put small 's' for the secondViewController.

Comment: I given another solution. I want to know that, in our both solution which one is better for space and time complexity. Did @Akhilrajtr or anybody know?

Comment: @UdanPirappu that solution uses `objectAtIndex:` and in question it says `without using "objectAtIndex:x"`

Comment: @Akhilrajr Oops! ok. But first time i follow simply as: '[[self navigationController]popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];' However, now i make program dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, but if you want to check whether or not secondViewController is in viewControllerStack, do this:

```
NSArray * viewControllerStack = // I'm assuming you have array here

if ([viewControllerStack containsObject:secondViewController]) {
    // 'secondViewController' in viewControllerStack
    // Pop secondViewController here
}
else {
    // 'secondViewController' NOT in viewControllerStack
    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: You correct in your understanding. And after checking, then display "secondViewController" without using "objectAtIndex".

Answer (score 0):

Try these solution:

```
for(int i=0;i<[[self.navigationController viewControllers]count];i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:i]);

    if([[[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[secondViewController class]]){

        [[self navigationController]popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:i] animated:YES];

    }
```